# Best way to define predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I have  a problem with defining procedures in Prolog.
I have two source files and want to consult Prolog engine with both of them.
This can be done by invoking Prolog as swipl -g “['1.pl','2.pl'].

Both of the files are generated by another program written in another programming language and i can't predict the exact content of the files beforehand.

The problem is that in one of the files there is always  a rule

```
predicate1(X):-predicate2(X).
```

But,sometimes the rule

```
predicate2(something):-body
```

does not exist in both of the files and i get a error "predicate2" is undefined, when executing some queries for predicate1.

If i include the line

```
:- dynamic(predicate2/2).
```

into one of the files it only  helps if predicate/2 is not defined in another file (otherwise i get something like "are you really sure you want to redefine the predicate2/2?". And here i don't want to redefine something to save the data from another file.

So,i have no idea how to make the predicate just "defined". I need a solution for SWI-Prolog or SICStus Prolog. (unfortunately the versions do not have a section for defining predicates,like visual Prolog)

Comment: A possible way is to include something like predicate2(blablabla..). in both files,but i don't like it,because sometimes there are queries of the type predicate2(X),and the set for X includes "blablabla.."

Comment: is there a special command for this? I didn't find something useful in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI Prolog you can avoid the error. Change the system behaviour using the ISO builtin

```
:- set_prolog_flag(unknown, Choice).
```

The Choice is one of (fail,warning,error).

So your command line will be:

```
swipl -g “set_prolog_flag(unknown,fail),['1.pl','2.pl']."
```

Another possibility: define a fake procedure

```
swipl -g “assert(predicate2(_):-fail),['1.pl','2.pl']."
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `predicate2/2` `multifile` with the ISO directive of same name. So in each of the files, you write at the top, or prior to any clauses of `predicate2/2`:

```
:- multifile(predicate2/2).
```

This, regardless of whether or not you are having clauses for that predicate.

---

The suggestion by @CapelliC is definitely a dangerous move. If you turn off all existence errors you will miss many legitimate errors!

For example, you declared `dynamic(predicate2/2)` but used `predicate2(_)`. So which arity do you want?

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, Prolog is not able to answer any question we formulate. For instance, if we
ask if Donald is a duck

```
?- isDuck(Donald) .
! ----------------------------------------
! Error 20 : Predicate Not Defined
! Goal : isDuck(_17610)
```

> Prolog will answer that it does not know anything about if “something”
>   is or is not a duck. What it is happening is that the logic predicate
>   `isDuck/1` is not defined (Predicate Not Defined), so Prolog is not
>   able to check if “something” is or is not a duck. As we will see
>   later, even if Prolog does not know what a duck is, it is possible to
>   teach it how to distinguish between what is a duck and what it is not.
>   As we said previously, Prolog is a dialogue language. In the dialogue
>   between the system and the programmer Prolog is not only able to
>   answer certain questions, but is also able to learn about what it does
>   not know. To answer the questions formulated by the programmer, Prolog
>   checks a knowledge base where everything is registered that Prolog
>   knows. In the beginning of the Prolog session, the knowledge base keep
>   a basic knowledge that includes, between other things, concepts and
>   definitions of natural number’s arithmetic. During the session it is
>   possible to increase this knowledge base, including definitions and
>   concepts that Prolog isn't familiar with (for instance the definition
>   of a duck), or also modifying and extending definitions that Prolog
>   knows (for instance, including new arithmetic operators for natural
>   numbers). Facts and rules express the knowledge base. Facts and rules
>   are syntactic representations of the first order Horn Clauses. So all
>   the Prolog’s knowledge is expressed using (almost) exclusively first
>   order logic. This is the reason why Prolog is said to be a logic
>   language. A program in Prolog is a set of facts and rules that express
>   certain knowledge.

---

Comment: This does not answer the question, which states that the predicate is defined but in a different file.