# List of predicates in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Is it possible to define a list, that consists of predicates and how do I call the predicates.

Also, is it possible to pass one predicate to another predicate (like passing atoms)?

Example:

```
pre1:- something.
pre2(Predicate1, List):-
    call(Predicate1),
    append([Predicate1], List, R),
    .....
```

Comment: The answer I think you're looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687306/best-way-to-define-predicate-in-prolog

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I added an example to better illustrate what I mean.

Comment: You might want to read [this thing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipterm.html%27%29%29)

Comment: @Mog this is promising, yet I cant find any examples

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve a bit more detailed? You already mention `call/1` in your example, so I can't see what else you need to know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store *predicates* in a list, but you can store *terms* (or functors) and call terms as *goals*.

Here's a predicate that tests whether a term has the properties described by a list of functors:

```
has_properties([], _).
has_properties([P|Ps], X) :-
    Goal =.. [P, X],            % construct goal P(X)
    call(Goal),
    has_properties(Ps, X).
```

Usage:

```
% is 4 a number, an integer and a foo?
?- has_properties([number, integer, foo], 4).
```

The answer to this query will depend on your definition of `foo/1`, of course. See my [explanation of `=..`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131628/166749) if needed.

**Edit**: as @false reports in the comments, it's not necessary to use `=..`, since `Goal =.. [P, X], call(Goal)` can be replaced by `call(P, X)` will have the same effect. It might still be worthwhile learning about `=..`, though, as you may encounter it in other people's code.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I need to get a value from the Goal after calling it

Comment: Please consider `call(P, X)` instead of `(=..)/2` and `call/1`! This is so much faster, cleaner and even more general!

Comment: @false: good point. However, the SWI manual suggests that `call/2` is not in ISO Prolog.

Comment: @RobFox I used Goal =.. [_, Args] to access the argumeters

Comment: @larsmans: That manual is clearly outdated. Since Cor.2:2012 it is ISO. Please refer to the [tag iso-prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info)!

Comment: @larsmans: Here is the [up-to-date SWI manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.9%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/metacall.html%27%29%29). Well, clearly a case why getting the standard is indispensable!

Comment: @false: amended the answer. I was indeed looking at the 5.10 manual, the version packaged in Debian.

Comment: @larsmans: Your amendment needs a clarification: The version with `call(P,X)` is more general, so it is not the same effect. `P` does not need to be an atom! `P` can be for example `between(1,10)`.

Comment: @false: the OP didn't express a requirement qua currying, but yes, that's a nice extra.

Comment: @larsmans: No curry involved! In FP this is partial application.