# Build compound predicate from list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

If I have a list of predicates in Prolog like `[flies, swims]`, how can I build a predicate that is the conjunction of all the predicates in the list, ie `fliesAndSwims(X) :- flies(X), swims(X).`?

Alternatively, is there a better way of building up a predicate at runtime like this without putting the component predicates in a list and building the compound one from them when needed?

EDIT:
So it turns out this is a duplicate of [List of predicates in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410082/list-of-predicates-in-prolog). I had previously found that answer, but I thought that it only returned whether a given atom matched every predicate in the list. I didn't realise that you can pass a variable instead of an atom and have it return every case that matches as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

library(lambda) is powerful, but it has a cost. If you think 'simpler is better' (wrt debugging, specially...) consider

```
call_unary_list([], _).
call_unary_list([P|Ps], X) :-
    call(P, X),
    call_unary_list(Ps, X).
```

let's compare the performances:

```
compare_call_list :-
    findall(flies, between(1,100000,_), L),
    time(call_unary_list(L, _)),
    time(maplist(call_unary(_), L)),
    time(maplist(X+\Pred^call(Pred,X), L)).

call_unary(X, P) :- call(P, X).

?- compare_call_list.
% 200,000 inferences, 0.123 CPU in 0.123 seconds (100% CPU, 1629657 Lips)
% 300,000 inferences, 0.145 CPU in 0.149 seconds (98% CPU, 2064184 Lips)
% 1,000,001 inferences, 1.286 CPU in 1.297 seconds (99% CPU, 777362 Lips)
true .
```

the call_unary/2 highlights the arguments swap that's required by the maplist meta predicate

Comment: @repeat: I like lambda, actually I used it many times. When using it, I found 'the hard way' some problems. So, specially for beginners, I just prefer explain more basic techniques...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to updating [Prolog's dynamic database](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/database.txt)... You could use a [meta-predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metapred) like [`maplist/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2), IMHO ideally in combination with [Prolog lambda expressions](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

First, some sample (super-incomplete) definitions of `flies/1` and `swims/1`:

```
flies(duck).
flies(eagle).

swims(penguin).
swims(ostrich).
swims(duck).
swims(kiwi).
swims(eagle).
```

Now let's do a query:

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).
true.

?- maplist(X+\Pred^call(Pred,X), [flies,swims]).
X = duck ;
X = eagle.
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks a lot. The lambda library worked well, but could you explain how you would do the same in vanilla prolog? I'm still learning so I want to know how the stuff I'm using works rather than blindly copying.

I'm guessing it's the equivalent of lambda/anonymous functions in other languages, just a convenience to let you define them inline rather than as a separate declaration?

Comment: Actually, `library(lambda)` **is** "vanilla" ISO Prolog:)  As stated on the page linked: "No syntax or compiler extension is needed."